# I need help fixxing CloudFront URL

Tags: amazon-cloudfront

My videos are in a S3 bucket and WordPress site is on Lightsail.

I have set up a cloudfront distribution so that the videos are served from cloudfront CDN instead of pulling from S3. The S3 bucket is public along with all the videos files in it.

The problem is that the cloudfront URL returns an error - **NoSuchKeyThe specified key does not exist.**

Anyone know how I can fix this?

thank you

Comment: Have you managed to successfully access _any_ objects via the CloudFront distribution (eg images)? If not, it suggests that the distribution is not configured to point to the Amazon S3 bucket. Can you show us what the "cloudfront url" looks like? (Feel free to change part of it to keep content private.)

Comment: are you able to view this video using direct S3 URL ? go to S3 click on object and view or  download ? if yes then problem with access level in bucket policy